# How to properly create context when using swift instead of Oc for KVO

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing

I'm recently learning coding IOS apps with swift and UIKIT(cuz my company's code base is still mainly OC, but i really wish to learn swift instead of oc which I'm assuming is stepping into history)

here is my question. for things in OC like :

```
[self.person addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

I can try create my context by something like:

```
static void *PersonAContext = &PersonAContext;
static void *PersonBContext = &PersonBContext;
```

However is i do this in swift:

```
observee.addObserver(observer:NSObject, forKeyPath: String, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
```

How do i initialzie an UnsafeMutableRawPointer? properlly for the same purpose? I went through apple document which is basically leading me to learn the subject of how to use pointer in swift entirely(which i assume i need to if wish do grow as better programer on swift??) But now i just want to simply use this context as a way to differentiate the Uiviewcontrollers that i'm monitering. How can i effectivly achieve that? Or is this an entriely outdated way to doing things now?(swift 5.4 in Xcode 12.5.1 is where i'm trying this out)

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, you should use the `context` parameter so that your observer code can correctly identify which observation it is reacting to.

With swift, you can explicitly associate the handler in a closure, so in your case you would write something like:

```swift
let token = self.person.observe(\.name, options: [.new]) { object, change in
    // write your handler here
}
```

1. Within the closure, you write the code to handle the changes
2. This method return an `NSKeyValueObservation`. In your observer you should create a property `var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?`. Using the above method for KVO returns this value. Assign `token` to this property. This is what keeps a strong reference to the KVO observation
3. You don't need to remove observers manually, when the observer class is destroyed, the observation parameter is destroyed, and the observation will be removed by the system.